# Content handling: DIV vs. full screen

Tags: javascript, css

Let's assume a simple application, which has at the top the following navigation (pseudo code):

```
<a href="?action=new">New</a>
<a href="?action=search">Search</a>
```

Below, there are different sections, i.e. for the "New" mask:

```
<div id="condition">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="Login" />
        <input type="text" name="First" />
        <a href="javascript:performSearch()">Perform search</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="results"
    <table>
    ..
    </table
</div>
```

Let's assume that the session times out and the user clicks on ...

- *New*: the content returned from the server will be loaded "full screen" and has to include header/footer/etc
- *Perform search*: the content will be displayed within the results DIV: should be only a short error message

**Question:**

- is there a way to identify via JavaScript (in the "error.html") if the current content is loaded into a DIV or "fullscreen"?
- should I always return an element which spans the whole browser window?
- or is there a different way to handle this situation?

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you want, but find it hard to understand what your question is. Is it about how to make an element span the whole browser window?

Comment: This is one of the most confusing "questions" I have ever seen on StackOverflow. You mention, HTML, PHP, Java, Javascript, CSS and something about an error. I have no clue what you're asking. Can you please show some of the code you're working on and try to rewrite your question with clarity in mind?

Comment: what do you mean by "fullscreen"? how does it related with "div"? i really get confused.

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the description with pseudo code.

Comment: Your changes doesn't really make it much clearer...

Comment: @MrG did you mean to accept my answer or downvote it? Because usually it's just one of the two options :)

Comment: That was a mistake which I can't fix - SO says "You're vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited". Please add a or remove a space, that will allow me to fix it. Tkx!

Comment: @Pekka: Done as well, tkx for pointing me in the right direction! It seems strange that I can accept/toggle the answer flag at any time, but votes are locked right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to identify via JavaScript (in the "error.html") if the current content is loaded into a DIV or "fullscreen"? Or is there a different way to handle this situation?

I don't think it really matters!

Not 100% sure this answers your question, but here's what I'd do:

Have an invisible `error` div in *every* page.

```
<div id="errordiv" style="display: none">Error!</div>
```

Make it span the whole browser window.

```
div#errordiv
 {
    position: fixed; // Works everywhere except IE 6
    left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white; // or whatever

  }
```

if an error occurs when you run your JavaScript (regardless in what context!), make the error div visible:

```
document.getElementById("errordiv").style.display = "block";
```

add the error message

```
document.getElementById("errordiv").style.innerHTML= 
                     "<h1>Error</h1>An error has occurred.....";
```

(of course, you'd wrap all this into one central `showError()` function)

if an error occurs during server-side handling, make it visible from the start (how to do that, differs from language to language).